# Proving that $g(x) = \frac{L}{2} x^Tx -f(x)$ is a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose we have a function $f\in {C^1_L}$ such that ${\lVert \nabla  f(x) - \nabla  f(y)\rVert}_2$ $\geqslant$ $L{\lVert x - y\rVert}_2$ for some $L>0$.

We take a function $g(x) = \frac{L}{2} x^Tx -f(x)$ we need to prove that g(x) is a convex function.

I tried to prove it in the following manner:

We know that to prove that a function is convex we need to prove that for $0<\alpha<1$ the given inequality holds true $g(\alpha x +(1-\alpha)y) \le \alpha g(x) + (1 - \alpha)g(y)$.

We take the LHS of the inequality and get $$ \frac{L}{2}[\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y]^T[\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y] - f(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y)$$

on solving it for 2-3 steps we get $$ \frac{L}{2}[\alpha \lVert x \rVert^2 + (1-\alpha)\lVert y \rVert^2)] - f(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y)$$

similarly, for the RHS term we get $$ \frac{L}{2}[\alpha \lVert x \rVert^2 + (1-\alpha)\lVert y \rVert^2)]  - [f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)]$$

the norm inequality gives us that f is monotonically increasing and thus convex, so RHS $\ge$ LHS and hence $g(x)$ is convex.

IS my proof correct? If not what else I need to do? any hints or suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a counterexample? Let $L = 1$ and $f(x) = x^2$. Or do you want to have "$\le$" in your very first inequality?

Comment: As it is, your statement is incorrect. as @gerw mentioned, you should reverse the sign on the condition on $f$. Your proof does not seem correct. How can you possibly get the same thing on the RHS and the LHS of your convexity condition for the quadratic part? The idea here is that you have a purely positive quadratic part, with Hessian$=L\cdot Id$, and you subtract something with "second derivatives" bounded by $L$ in some weak sense. This gives you a result that has "positive" second derivatives, again in some weak sense, because you are assuming that $f$ is only $C^1$.